# C# - path with spaces in it

Tags: c#, .net, path

For legacy-reasons, the current C# project I'm working on uses INI files to store various pieces of information. Accessing those INIs is done through importing kernel32.dll  and linking in functions from said DLL such as `GetPrivateProfileStringA`.

Problem is that the path of the ini files may contain white spaces and I found out that the ini-related functions that are imported through that DLL don't work when the path passed as argument to them contains white spaces.

> This is a sample path: "C:\Users\xxxxx\workspace\me\proj
>   name\inis\Index.ini"

I can pretty much assume that surrounding 'proj name' with quotes would solve this, but I am looking for a clean solution to the problem, other than parsing the path and adding quotes.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to surround the *entire path* with quotes to make it work (not just the chunk with the space in it).

Comment: or perhaps use pure .net solutions to read / write ini files instead of winapi. https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Mc5IVfCuBoue-AXPgIGgDQ#q=reading+and+writing+ini+files+in+c%23

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. There was also another problem in the legacy code that was masked by this.